# getting size from one image and applying to another in php

Tags: php, image, aspect-ratio

I am writing a function in php to show an image if you are logged in, but show a placeholder if you are not.  The placeholder is just a white JPG with text on top so I am not too concerned with the aspect ratio.

Up to now, I have just given the image tag a width, and let it figure out the height.

When I am replacing with a placeholder however I would like to keep the size consistant with the image.

Is it possible to pull what size the image would come out to, and insert this into the placeholder.

For example, if I have a 500x500 px image, but feed the image tag a width of 50px, it will make it a 50x50 px image... I want to  apply this to the placeholder.

Comment: You could use CSS resizing. `<img src='http://url/to/image.png' style='max-width: 50px;' />`

Comment: Have you looked at `getimagesize(string $filename [, array &$imageinfo ])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$imgSrc = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/638751551457103872/KN-NzuRl.png";
echo "<img src=" . $imgSrc . " style='height: 50px; width: 50px'/>";
?>
```

Don't know if that's what you were asking but that's that.

Comment: Sorry, its a little more complicated. If I feed in a 333 X 120 pixel image, and want it to display by 50 pixels wide,  I can feed the image tag a width of 50 pixels, and it will figure out the correct aspect ratio for height.  I want to take this auto generated aspect ratio, and apply it to the placeholder

Comment: @RobTex So what you want is for this to be a feature of a placeholder? Is that it or I'm just not understanding something. Sorry :(